# Html select option not working for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a page where if your on desktop you have a side menu on the left and images on the right and if your on mobile then the side menu disappears and a select option shows up on top. What my page does is if you click on the menu item it sorts the images on the right according to the category you clicked on, the problem I'm having is that for mobile the select menu isn't doing that. If I just resize the browser to get the select menu it works, but if I try to use it on mobile it doesn't work and I don't see any errors to point me in the right direction. I'm not sure where I went wrong.

I've managed to make a jsfiddle that shows what is happening: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/joth06fd/)

Here is my code.

This is my products.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="body-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 product_category">
                    <h1>
                        Products
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group mobile-category-selector">
                        <select id="category-selector" class="form-control">
                            <option id="all" class="product-selector">All</option>
                            <option class="product-selector" id="kitten">Kitten</option>
                            <option class="product-selector" id="puppy">Puppy</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 ml-15">
                    <div class="category-menu">
                        <ul class="nav flex-column list-group">
                            <li class="category-item">
                                <a class="product-selector list-group-item active-product" href="javascript:void(0);" id="all">All</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="category-item">
                                <a class="product-selector list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="kitten">
                                    Kitten
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="category-item">
                                <a class="product-selector list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0);" id="puppy">
                                    Puppy
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-12 product-list">
                    <div id="parent">
                        <div class="row grid-container">
                            <div class="product_items col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 kitten">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QjGYAbbb.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />

                                        <p>
                                            Kitten 1
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product_items col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 kitten">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LKCEwxob.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />

                                        <p>
                                            Kitten 2
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product_items col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 puppy">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Vvpmx9Y.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />

                                        <p>
                                            Puppy 1
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product_items col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 puppy">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9LnDyY5.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />

                                        <p>
                                            Puppy 2
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product_items col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 kitten">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zJMe7Yfb.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />

                                        <p>
                                            Kitten 5
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my css

```
body{
    background-color: #c5cbd1;
}

.ml-15{
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.body-content{
    padding-bottom: 234px;
}

.row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.mobile-category-selector{
    display: none;
}

.category-menu {
    display: block;
}

.category-menu ul li a {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.category-item{
    width: 100%;
}

.list-group-item {
    padding: 8px 8px;
    line-height: 5px;
    background: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.active-product {
    background: #D3D3D3 !important;
}

.product-list{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.product_items a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.product_items img {
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 25px black;
}

.product_items > p {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.product_items div {
    background: #8b9dc3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.product_items div:hover {
    background: #868282 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.product_items p {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media(max-width: 992px){
  .mobile-category-selector{
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
  }

  .category-menu{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and this is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $select = $('.product-selector').click(function() {
      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('#parent > .grid-container > div').fadeIn(450);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
        $('#parent > .grid-container > div').not($el).hide();
      }

      $select.removeClass('active-product');
      $(this).addClass('active-product');
    })
});
```

UPDATE:
So I noticed this when I was trying to figure out the problem. I'm not sure if this means anything

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: I am not experiencing your described problem in FF. Where have you tested?

Comment: I'm testing it in chrome

Comment: You need a WebKit then....

Answer (score 0):

Try with this var $select = $('.product-selector').on('click touch'function()

Comment: Hope this will work on("click touchstart" function()